# Can I use nools on the clientside

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a rules engine to simplify my code a bit. The only good solution that I see is nools for nodejs. As I am not that familiar with nodejs, I wanted to see if anybody has used nools for client side rules and if it is even possible to use nools on client side.

Comment: *please* read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before posting... your question isn't really fit for SO as it's expecting opinion-based answers, and is overly broad.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question to represent what I really wanted to ask, hopefully eliminating vagaries.